# How to remember whether box is checked or unchecked (on click) with localstorage and also save a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

### **Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nng6L/7/**

So what I want to do is the following:

1. I want to set a value in localstorage, of **`1`** if box is checked, or **`0`** if box is unchecked
2. When page is reloaded, if box was checked then it stays checked, having fetched the value from localstorage
3. I want to be able to display either a **`1`** or a **`0`** in plain text, having fetched the aforementioned value from localstorage.

Here is my code, but it is not working (when page is reloaded, box is not checked; and **`null`** is returned instead of a **`1`** or a **`0`**):

**script.js**

```
    // here is to set item in localstorage when you click the check box.
    vvvvvvv = document.getElementById('xxxx');      
    vvvvvvv.onclick = function() {
        if(document.getElementById('xxxx').checked=true) {
            localStorage.setItem('yyyyyyy', "1");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('yyyyyyy', "0");
        }
    }

    // here is to fetch the item stored in local storage, and use that value
    // to check or uncheck the box based on localstorage value.
    zzzzzzz = localStorage.getItem('yyyyyyy');
    if (zzzzzzz === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('yyyyyyy', "0");
            document.getElementById("xxxx").checked=false;
        }
        else {
            if (zzzzzzz === "1") {
                document.getElementById("xxxx").checked=true;
            } else if (zzzzzzz === "0") {
                document.getElementById("xxxx").checked=false;
            }
        }
```

**output.js**

```
    // here is to output the value to the web page so we can know 
    // what value is stored in localstorage.
    wwwwwwww = localStorage.getItem('yyyyyyy');
    document.write(wwwwwwww);
```

**page.html**

```
<!-- here is the check box for which the scripts above are based from -->
<input type="checkbox" id="xxxx">Do you like summer?
<br><br>

<!-- here is where it will display the value from localstorage -->
<script src="output.js">
```

Comment: Just to be sure : are you opening your file in http:// (not in file://) ?

Comment: can u create jsfiddle for ur code

Comment: dystroy - yes, actually it's relative links, just like above, that is the exact code above... @iJay ok I will create a jsfiddle..

Comment: I'm not sure you got my question : are you opening the first file in your browser with a `http://` URL or a `file://` URL (the later one can't work) ?

Comment: @iJay here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nng6L/

Comment: @dystroy neither, your answer is irrelevant. I'm not opening with file though yea I know that. ;)

Comment: You have a few errors. For example a syntax error : `} } else`.

Comment: It is being set as '0', as can be seen by putting a `console.log` in straight after getting the value from localStorage.

Comment: @Archer, if it is being set to 0 or 1 then why is it not outputting?

Comment: @dystroy, i see the  `} } else` now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed some unnecessary bits of the script and tidied it a little and came up with this...

```
// here is to set item in localstorage when you click the check box.

vvvvvvv = document.getElementById('xxxx');      

vvvvvvv.onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('xxxx').checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('yyyyyyy', "1");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('yyyyyyy', "0");
    }
}

// here is to fetch the item stored in local storage, and use that value
// to check or uncheck the box based on localstorage value.

zzzzzzz = localStorage.getItem('yyyyyyy');

console.log(zzzzzzz);

if (zzzzzzz === "1") {
    document.getElementById("xxxx").checked=true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("xxxx").checked=false;
}
```

Here's a working jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/nng6L/5/

Check the checkbox and refresh the page to see it work.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.. Too bad people are downvoting this question, because it means I can't give you an upvote. :(

Comment: The 2 are not linked, but don't worry about that.  I'm happy to help.

Comment: Yes, because since people downvoted me they take away points so i have less than 25 points so i cannot upvote you. :(

Comment: Ah I see.  No worries anyway.  It's not all about the points ;)

Comment: for some reason the only place this works is in jsfiddle. I tried putting it even in a blank html file but still doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Àre you putting the script in a `window.onload` event handler, or in the page after the checkbox?

Comment: Console gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null for line 5. Unchose as best answer until this can be solved somewhere other than jsfiddle.

Comment: No I am not using window.onload.. let me try.

Comment: jsFiddle (by default) wraps the script in an onload handler, so that will be your issue.  Make sure all the above script is in the handler and it's fine :)

Comment: SUCCESS >> I wrapped the code with this: `$(document).ready(function(){ });` (jquery is added to page already)

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working.  Now make some real variable names ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntax errors in your code, which is why it is failing to store the value in localStorage. For example, here is one:

Equality operator in your onclick (== instead of =):

```
if(document.getElementById('xxxx').checked == true) {
```

or just:

```
if(document.getElementById('xxxx').checked) {
```

Another one:

Extra dangling `{` before the `else` as pointed out by dystroy.

Now it is working just fine:

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nng6L/6/

You did not fix the second! There was an extra `{` dangling before the `else`.

Comment: That's not the answer, but worth pointing out to him.  Also, he doesn't even need `== true`.  He can just say `if (document.getElementById('xxxx').checked)`

Comment: @user2651403 What's not correct?  In your code you have `checked = true`, which will set it to true, not compare it.  You need `checked == true` to compare it.  This is definitely relevant as your code will not work if you leave it as it is.  This is not the main problem but it *is* a problem :)

Comment: Please check thoroughly for syntax errors. You have a couple of them. dystroy pointed one in his comment. Probably because of this, the js is giving problems, as the value is perhaps never written to the localstorage.

Comment: @user2651403 I have already pointed one in the answer. Another one was pointed by dystroy. So you can't say that we are not pointing them out! Please have a look at console. Any errors there?

Comment: @abhitalk no, your jsfiddle actually does not work. Take a look - reload page, box is not checked.

Comment: @user2651403 It was just meant to give you hints to nudge in right direction. It was never meant to provide you with a full complete working product. I only tried to help. :) Anyways, cheers, you got your problem solved and have an accepted answer and that is more important!